# Python regex re.sub maintain double quotes in input string

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
item  = '"PUBLIC".test'
re.sub(r"\b{0}\b".format(item),"(from {0} limit 0)".format(item),item)
```

Required result :

```
(from "PUBLIC".test limit 0)
```

Result obtained: (input item is not replaced)

```
"PUBLIC".test
```

This works if the item - > does not have quotes

```
import re
item  = 'PUBLIC.test'
re.sub(r"\b{0}\b".format(item),"(from {0} limit 0)".format(item),item)
```

Result :-> (from PUBLIC.test limit 0)

How can I get the result item to  "from {item} limit 0" with maintaining the double quotes in input string item

Comment: `r"\b{0}\b".format(item)` => `r"(?!\B\w){0}(?<!\w\B)".format(re.escape(item))`

Comment: For those who want the required result without using `re.sub`, you can just concatenate: `item = '"PUBLIC".test'; req = '(from ' + item + 'limit 0)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  it works. Can you post this as answer